# Pandas, combine unique value from two column into one column while preserving order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

I have data in four column as shown below. There are some values which are present in column 1, and some value of column 1 is again duplicated in column 3. I would like to combine column 1 with 3, while removing the duplicates from column 3. I would also like to preserve the order of column. Column 1 is associated with column 2 and column 3 is associated with column 4, so it would be nice if I can move column 1 items with column 2 and column 3 items with column 4 during merge. Any help will be appreciated.

Input table:

| Item | Price | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 105 | Truck | 54822 |
| Chair | 20 | Pen | 1 |
| Cup | 2 | Car | 105 |
|  |  | Glass | 1 |

Output table:

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 105 |
| Chair | 20 |
| Cup | 2 |
| Truck | 54822 |
| Pen | 1 |
| Glass | 1 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. Please show relevant data as text in the question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: @gupta - Your column 1 is sorted. Do you _also like to preserve the order of column 1_ if it isn't sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After separating the input table into the left and right part, we can concatenate the left hand items with the unduplicated right hand items quite simply with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

# this initial section only recreates your sample input table
from io import StringIO
input = pd.read_table(StringIO("""| Item  | Price | Item | Price |
|-------|-------|------|-------|
| Car   | 105   | Truck| 54822 |
| Chair |  20   | Pen  |     1 |
| Cup   |   2   | Car  |   105 |
|       |       | Glass|     1 |
"""), ' *\| *', engine='python', usecols=[1,2,3,4], skiprows=[1], keep_default_na=False)
input.columns = list(input.columns[:2])*2

# now separate the input table into the left and right part
left  = input.iloc[:,:2].replace("", pd.NA).dropna().set_index('Item')
right = input.iloc[:,2:]                            .set_index('Item')
# finally construct the output table by concatenating without duplicates
output = pd.concat([left, right[~right.index.isin(left.index)]])
```

---

```
       Price
Item        
Car      105
Chair     20
Cup        2
Truck  54822
Pen        1
Glass      1
```

Comment: Dear Armali, Thank you so much for your kind help. It's working perfect. I cannot upvote due to low point but i will upvote once I get enough points. Thank you so much. Best wishes. gupta

Comment: I have a question, what changes I need to introduce If I want to repeat the same for column number 5, 6, 7 and 8? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want it A) only _for column number 5, 6, 7 and 8_, or B) for all column pairs 1&2, 3&4, 5&6 and 7&8 to be combined in one output column pair?

Comment: And which columns can contain spaces like 1&2 above?

Comment: Thank you dear for your response. Actually, I have some big files (like 2400 columns in each) and want to do the same thing like column 1-4, with 5-8, 9-12 and so on. so it would be really helpful if you guide me that how to do  "A) only for column number 5, 6, 7 and 8," . Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 5 to 8 you just have to replace in the `left  =` line the `:2` with `4:6` (because indexes start at 0, `4` is column 5, and because the end `6` is always excluded, it's index 4 to 5) and in the `right =` line the `2:` with `6:8`. Maybe you can see it [online](https://paiza.io/projects/wI03quqcl3Y-crdFJPyGnQ).